# DoesNotExist at /cart/ Product matching query does not exist

Tags: django, error-handling, django-views

This snippet of code gives me the following error message:

```py
def cartItems(cart):
    items=[]
    for item in cart:
        items.append(Product.objects.get(id=item))
    return items
```

> DoesNotExist at /cart/ Product matching query does not exist

Answer (score 0):

That's because Django can't find a `Product` in the db with the id stored in `item` on one or all of the iterations. You need to see whats installed in `item`, do a `.filter(id=item)` and check if it `.exists()` then append it to your list.

When you use `objects.get(**kwargs)`, if the query doesn't find anything which matches your search, Django raises a `Product.DoesNotExist` exception, hence you found yourself there.